# Only first LED in strand lights up. When I reverse polarity, it blows the fuse

Tags: led

I have a continuous strand of 176 5v LEDs on my house (power injected every 3 meters).  They worked fine last year.  My home-made arduino controllor and PS kicked the bucket so I bought a Hinks Pix Pro controller this year.

On this strand, in test mode, only the first LED lights up.  I thought maybe I reversed the polarity some how so I swapped it around and it blew the fuse on the controller port.

So I guess I have 2 questions:

- Why does only the first LED come on and and stay red?
- Why does reversing the polarity blow the fuse?  (Its only powered by the 1 PS)

> LED Strip: CHINLY WS2812B (HC-F5V-30L-30LED-W) 5V
> Power: 9W/M
> Tested @ 15% power

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does only the first LED come on and and stay red?

The first LED in the strand was likely damaged by ESD, sticking it on red and preventing data from passing along to the LEDs downstream of it. This is a pretty common issues with WS2812 strands from my experience. The fix would be to replace the first LED or simply remove it and make the next LED the first LED.

> Why does reversing the polarity blow the fuse? (Its only powered by the 1 PS)

The LEDs probably lack reverse polarity protection, and feeding it -5V likely fried one or more of the LEDs in the strand and created a short circuit. The resultant overcurrent then blew the fuse. Note that while actual LEDs are generally tolerant of -5V, that doesn't necessarily apply to the ICs in "smart" LEDs such as the WS2812.

Comment: Thanks Gene.  Could you explain what ESD is?  (I can google ofcourse but for anyone else who may stumble across this.  I suppose I will do the painstaking task of replacing that first node *cries*

Comment: you can just short (connect) the data line before and after the bad LED to skip over that node w/o re-splicing power lines.

Comment: @dandavis Nice tip!  I can't up vote but, thanks ;)

Comment: @flashsplat Electrostatic discharge. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge

Comment: I did splice into the strip after the first LED and was able to go 21 LEDs :D... 21/176 not bad!  I'm going to rip it all out lol.

Answer (score 4):

> LED Strip: CHINLY WS2812B (HC-F5V-30L-30LED-W) 5V Power: 9W/M Tested @ 15% power

Cheap Cheese junk, set your expectations accordingly.

This isn’t an AC mains application, so I am not too worried about safety. Anything that touches AC power must be UL listed.

> Why does only the first LED come on and and stay red?

It’s defective or has failed.  Given the source, there is no surprise here. Just replace it and take it in stride. The stuff is so cheap...  It’s  not worth spending ANY time fussing over.

> Why does reversing the polarity blow the fuse?

Because DC stuff really cares about polarity, and I’m not telling you anything you don’t already know.

I think you were working the ‘failure tree’ in your.mind with the cognitive bias of excluding hardware failure... and thought “reversed polarity/mis-marked board” was most likely, and easy to test.  Unfortunately that stuff does not necessarily have reverse voltage protection.